# Use another df to replace column values

Tags: python, pandas, replace

---

Hello I have two df such as

**df1**

```
Ancient New 
Seq1.1  Seq1.1_A
Seq2    Se2.4_3
```

and another

**df2**

```
COL1 COL2
A    Seq1.1
B    Plants
C    YP_OODDD
D    Seq2
```

and I would like to replace `COL2` values corresponding to the `df.Ancient` column and replace it by their corresponding `df1.New`

and get

```
COL1 COL2
A    Seq1.1_A
B    Plants
C    YP_OODDD
D    Se2.4_3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) with `Series` created by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and selecting volumn `New`:

```
df2['COL2'] = df2['COL2'].replace(df1.set_index('Ancient')['New'])
print (df2)
  COL1      COL2
0    A  Seq1.1_A
1    B    Plants
2    C  YP_OODDD
3    D   Se2.4_3
```

Answer (score 1):

set the index of 1st dataframe to ancient `df.set_index` and then use `df2.col2.replace(df.new)` pass series as an argument.

```
    df=pd.DataFrame({"col1":["john","amber"],"col2":["a","h"]})
    df2=pd.DataFrame({"ab":["m","g"],"ful":["abraham","heard"]})
    print(df,"\n",df2)
    df2.set_index("ab",inplace=True)
    df.col2=df.col2.replace(df2['ful'])
    df
```

output:

```
        col1 col2
    0   john    a
    1  amber    h 

       ab      ful
    0  a  abraham
    1  h    heard

        col1    col2
    0   john    abraham
    1   amber   heard
```